# Running .jar file in terminal is causing a website login popup

Tags: java, authentication, popup, jsoup, ubuntu-16.04

I have been working on a program. Part of the program is a multithread piece of code where thread 1. searches for a term on a search engine, threads 2._0 to 2._7 receive the search results and read the contents of the links, and thread 3. creates word bags out of the resulting link contents (full code of this class can be found at https://github.com/ikb-a/ci/blob/summer2015/src/main/java/openEval/MultithreadSimpleOpenEval.java).
While running the code I would get a popup asking for login credentials whenever one of the thread 2. would hit a website requiring authentication (see image below)[image: Example of original pop up message stating: Please provide your username and password. Site: www.philippineexaminer.com Realm: Access Restricted (suspend)]

This is a major problem to my program, as the popup freezes the thread until a human presses the cancel button.

After searching on the internet I found a similar problem which was related to eclipse, so I exported the project as a runnable .jar and re-ran it expecting the message to not appear. However it did (see below):
[image: Same message as above, but appearing on terminal]

I then looked at the log messages that my program was creating, and found that thread 2._1 printed the following message:

> 2._1 Reading: philippineexaminer.com/CSS
>   Organized Filipino Organizations Abroad Being Asked to Help Street Children...
>   http://www.philippineexaminer.com/CSS/

All other threads had finished, except for thread 3. which was waiting on 2._1. After I pressed the cancel button on the popup I got the following log, which is what should have happened without a pop up appearing:

> 2._1 Unable to read http://www.philippineexaminer.com/CSS/ CAUSE: org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=401, URL=http://www.philippineexaminer.com/CSS/

Below is the code extract which is where the program is freezing:

```
try {
    if (verbose)
        System.out.println("2." + name + " Reading: " + link);
    // read the contents of the website
    // TODO: set jsoup so as to reject any website that
    // request authentication
    String websiteAsString = Jsoup.connect(link.getLink())
                                    .userAgent(
                                            "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0")
                                    .referrer("http://www.google.com").get().text();
    if (!websiteAsString.isEmpty()) {
        if (verbose)
            System.out.println("2." + name + " Adding result to contents");
        contents.add(websiteAsString);
        if (memoizeLinkContents) {
            memoizedLinkContents.put(link.getLink(), websiteAsString);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (verbose)
        System.err.println("2." + name + " Unable to read " + link.getLink() + " CAUSE: " + e);
    if (memoizeLinkContents) {
        memoizedLinkContents.put(link.getLink(), "");
    }
}
```

From the log I know it is freezing on the line with the Jsoup call, but Jsoup cannot create a pop up window nor execute javascript. Also, I know that the call link.getLink() cannot be responsible, as it is a simple retrieval of information (code of link's class "SearchResult" below):

```
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * An object which holds one search result from an engine such as Google Search.
 * This class is immutable.
 *
 */
public class SearchResult implements Serializable {

    /**
     * serial version UID generated by eclipse
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1239745645367856189L;
    /**
     * Title of this webpage according to the search engine.
     */
    private final String title;

    /**
     * link to this webpage according to the search engine.
     */
    private final String link;

    /**
     * Snippet of the text in this webpage according to the search engine.
     */
    private final String snippet;

    public SearchResult(String title, String link, String snippet) {
        super();
        this.title = title;
        this.link = link;
        this.snippet = snippet;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the title of this result (the title of this webpage).
     */
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the link to this webpage.
     */
    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a snippet of text from the webpage (typically containing some or
     * all of the words in the query that produced this result).
     */
    public String getSnippet() {
        return snippet;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s\n%s\n%s\n", getTitle(), getSnippet(), getLink());
    }

    /**
     * An object is equal to this if the object is also a {@link SearchResult},
     * with the same values for {@link #getTitle()}, {@link #getLink()} and
     * {@link #getSnippet()}.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof SearchResult)) {
            return false;
        }
        SearchResult o = (SearchResult) obj;
        return this.getLink().equals(o.getLink()) && this.getTitle().equals(o.getTitle())
                && this.getSnippet().equals(o.getSnippet());
    }

}
```

Anyone have any ideas as to what could be causing this behaviour?
I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Memory: 3.7 GiB
Processor: Intel® Pentium(R) CPU 2127U @ 1.90GHz × 2 
Graphics: Intel® Ivybridge Mobile 
OS Type:64-bit
Disk:487.9 GB

The full code of the class in question can be found at https://github.com/ikb-a/ci/blob/summer2015/src/main/java/openEval/MultithreadSimpleOpenEval.java

Although this class does not contain the main method, it is one of the four classes where the link http://www.philippineexaminer.com/CSS/ is used. The other classes are the SearchResult class (as seen above), and 2 search engine classes, which can't be responsible as that would lead to thread 1. and not thread 2._1 freezing.

I've attempted to reproduce the pop up in isolation using the following code:

```
package PlanIt.monthSuggestion.trainingDataGeneration;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

public class Exp5 {

    public Exp5() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String websiteAsString = Jsoup.connect("http://www.philippineexaminer.com/CSS/")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com").get().text();
        System.out.println(websiteAsString);

    }

}
```

However, instead of a pop up I get the desired result, a 401 error message:

> Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=401, URL=http://www.philippineexaminer.com/CSS/
>       at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:537)
>       at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
>       at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
>       at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:194)
>       at PlanIt.monthSuggestion.trainingDataGeneration.Exp5.main(Exp5.java:15)

Comment: Your first code snippet have one close bracket in advance in the *catch*. It is a typo?

Comment: In the site was used basic authentication.
Check this http://www.javacodeexamples.com/jsoup-basic-authentication-example/808

Comment: @MarioSantini The first code snippet is fine (the close bracket in front on the catch is closing the try statement).

Comment: @Hasanaga I don't want jsoup to authenticate; I want it to throw a 401 exception. The problem is that instead of throwing a 401, something (not sure if it's Ubuntu, Jsoup, etc...) is causing a login popup to appear, freezing the thread until a human intervenes.

Comment: @MaximilianSarte please check it careful, there in there is a more closing bracket in the *if* statement inside the *catch*.

Comment: @MarioSantini Yes, my mistake you are correct. I copied an extra closing bracket by accident, this code snippet lies within a while loop iterating through link objects, and I copied the closing bracket of the loop as well. I will edit the code snippet.

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem though. Any ideas?